# Error: Could not find or load main class App Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App on VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Java online wants to say hello world but VSCode don't, why, and how do i solve this,
Error: Could not find or load main class App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App

Comment: Yes, and it don't worked.

Comment: i mean how you compile it?

Comment: I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVJlck1WMX8, and it din't solved at all.

Comment: Check if you are in the good folder. Show me what you did?

Comment: Did you import package in your .java file? Can you show your code if convenient?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's just a basic system.out.println code, but no code works at all, i just get Error: Could not find or load main class App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App

Comment: @GuilhermeRibeiro. Clean java language server workspace from command palette then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few minutes ago and this is how I solved it.

**Solution**:

> Restart VS Code

Then run the program again.

Just ensure that the main class is declared correctly and if your class is in a package, include the package name at the top.

```
package package_name
```

Example:

```
package Games;

public class MoveSquare {
    public static void main(String []arg){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```